# Function of qnorm() in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I have read the documentation on `qnorm()` but could not really understand what it does. Can you please answer in detail what `qnorm()` does?

note-Please excuse me for asking such a simple question. I am a beginner at R.

Comment: Basically it is inverse gaussian CDF. For any distribution D in **R**, dD is PDF, pD is CDF, qD is inverse CDF, and rD is sampling according to PDF

Answer (score 7):

The function `qnorm()` aims to find the boundary value, A in `P(X < A)`, given the probability P.

For example, suppose you want to find the 85th percentile of a normal distribution whose mean is 70 and whose standard deviation is 3. Then you ask for:

```
qnorm(0.85,mean=70,sd=3)
[1] 73.1093
```

From https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tigerstats/vignettes/qnorm.html

Answer (score 5):

> "The idea behind qnorm is that you give it a probability, and it
>   returns the number whose cumulative distribution matches the
>   probability. For example, if you have a normally distributed random
>   variable with mean zero and standard deviation one, then if you give
>   the function a probability it returns the associated Z-score"

*from*  http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/probability.html

You can further refer to the above link to read up more on the same.